# Making an omni anntena for PA+LNA+Antenna

Tags: antenna, nrf24l01

I have several [NRF24L01 RF modules](https://freematics.com/store/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=80) that I would like to use to transmit data from a car to a ground station.

When testing the modules, I have found that the data transmission is only successful when the two antennas are facing each other. So after some research, I have learned that there are two different types of antenna: omni and directional.

I am wondering if it is possible to take the signal from the module antenna and resend it using a separate omni antenna, so that the data can be received at the ground station without relying on the antennas facing each other. Is this setup feasible?

Sorry if I am asking something that may be foolish but I don't have a lot of experience in this field. Thanks for answering and if you have any other ideas I would be happy to hear them.

Answer (score 0):

Try two vertical (whip) quarter-wave antennas with ground counter-poise under the whip, for predictable impedance and circularly-consistent radiation.

See police cars with several antennas on the top? These are whips, used in groups to allow peaking and nulling of responses, perhaps to cancel intentional jamming.